# DependencyInjection: Initialize class, before it is called (required)?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-core

First of all, I'm using Microsoft's dependency injection package. (ServiceProvider, ServiceCollection) which is going pretty well so far, except for this issue.

I have classes, which I register to my DI like this

```
this.AddSingleton<IAppWorker, AppWorker>();
this.AddSingleton<IAppController, AppController>();
```

These classes never get accessed, but they call a method inside their constructors. Do I really need to explicitly resolve the class, and call the method outside of the constructor?

Or is there a way to make it just initialize a new instance, and store it for when I need to resolve it? I'm pretty new to this and its hard to know what to even search for.

Is there a special name for this? Or is it just not possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the instances in the composition root and add them to the DI container using the [`AddSingleton<TService>(IServiceCollection, TService)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddSingleton__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection___0_) overload.

> Adds a singleton service of the type specified in `TService` with an instance specified in *implementationInstance* to the specified `IServiceCollection`.

```
var instance1 = new AppWorker();
services.AddSingleton<IAppWorker>(instance1);

var instance2 = new AppController();
services.AddSingleton<IAppController>(instance2);
```

Reference [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish. It's advisable to avoid adding logic to the constructor. It would be better to resolve these instances using constructor injection and call the methods when you need them.

If you are new to this, I would suggest "Dependency Injection in .NET book (https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-in-dot-net-second-edition).